# Avoid reflow while editing ordered input ng-repeat on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm experiencing some problems while inputing user data into ordered fields displayed with Angular ng-repeat.

Say that you want some values to display on a list, and those values might be editable. At the same time, you are ordering that data. Due to how ng-model works and Angular reflow cycle, if the value of one input surpases another one while still editing, you'll find yourself typing on the wrong field. Look at this example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myrow', Row);
app.controller('controller', Controller);


function Controller () {
  this.order = '-value';
  this.inputs = [
    {value: 1, tag: "Peas"},
    {value: 2, tag: "Apples"},
    {value: 3, tag: "Potatos"}
  ];
}
function Row($compile, $sce){
  var linker = function($scope, $element, $attrs){
    var template = '<div>- <input type="number" ng-model="data.value"><span ng-bind="data.tag"></span></div>';
  a = $element.html(template);
  $element.html(template);
    $compile($element.contents())($scope);
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        data: "="
    },
    link: linker
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  List:
   <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.inputs | orderBy: ctrl.order">
    <div myrow data="item"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've made this simplified example as the original component has thousands of lines and some dependencies. Here this problem is not reproduced exactly, yet, when you write, sometimes the input loses focus, thing that, for example, doesn't happen when not compiling on the directive (which is completly necessary in my real code). Any ideas on how to solve this? Is it possible to activate ng-model update on change instead of on user typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-model-options` and its `updateOn` property so that your model is updated only when user leaves the field.

You can see how it works here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions (There is a sample in the 'Triggering and debouncing model updates' section)

example:

```
<input ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```